# Postfix: on multi-recipient e-mails of same domain, how do you remove all but one (first) address?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, imap

We have a shared IMAP mailbox for a business. Customers are not used to not having to CC tons of people with us, so they CC everybody, which creates noisy duplicates in our shared inbox.

How can I get `postfix-3.0` to rewrite the To field on mail receive, deleting off all but the first instance of e-mail addresses from `domain.com`?

`To: Joe Rabbit <joe@domain.com>, Sally Fox <sally@domain.com>` needs to become just `To: Joe Rabbit <joe@domain.com>`

Comment: Why don't you setup one mailbox which receives mails in behalf of all tour colleagues and share this folder?

Comment: @sebix I'm not sure I follow? An example?

Comment: Do you receive more than one copy of the message to the shared mailbox?  You may fix it in other ways.  Which shared mailbox implementation do you use?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip `dovecot-2.2.16`

Comment: I have seen quite different meanings/interpretations of "shared mailbox".  I would like to know EXACTLY which one creates "noisy DUPLICATES".  Dovecot may deliver MANY versions of "shared mailbox".

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip We have an IMAP subfolder `DomainMail` (fake name), everybody is subscribed to it (Thunderbird). All `@domain.com` e-mails are server-side `sieve`-filtered into this mailbox, no messages go to anyone's individual inbox. All outgoing message copies are also configured to go to `DomainMail` by configuring Thunderbird accordingly, but that's beside the point. Is this an understandable description?

Comment: All individuals are recipients of the mails and all individual accounts receive this mail and it is filtered to a directory inside the account? My suggestions is to have one address e.g. `all@example.com` which not an alias but a mailbox. This mailbox participates in the Shared Folder and delivers its mails there. Thus you receive the newsletter only via the Shared Folder, it's not directly delivered.

Comment: @sebix There's multiple business reasons why a generic shared e-mail address would be sub-optimal and cause other types distress, so it would be just swapping one problem for another. But you may be on to something with this "rewrite to generic" idea, perhaps it's some sort of a de-duplication step that can be used. Have to think about an implementation method for it though.

Comment: *Perhaps*, postfix was wrong tool to this kind of this duplication problem. Remember that duplication was happened **after** postfix, as a messenger, deliver email to sieve-filtered mailbox.

Comment: And your idea about removing all but first recipient, perhaps it won't work. Postfix get the list of email recipient, not by parsing the `To:` header. Instead  some mail client told postfix to deliver an email to some recipients when SMTP transaction using `RCPT TO` command